# Using an emsp; in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, whitespace

As I have a background in the publishing industry, I prefer to use fixed-width spaces like em spaces. However, IE6 displays a box when I use `&emsp;`, which really bugs me. Can I do a javascript replace just for IE6, or should I just not use em spaces?

**Edit**
Just to prove that it's not just my computer, MercerTraieste usefully linked to this image:

[Example of incorrect emsp entity display http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6207/20090810154159.png](http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6207/20090810154159.png)

Comment: The behavior can be seen here http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6207/20090810154159.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps IE6 uses a font without an em space. Missing characters are often shown as boxes. If this is true then the question is not *why does IE6 display a box instead of an em space?*, but instead *why does IE6 not use the font that has an em space?*

You say that you are using Georgia. On my computer I did not find an em space in the Georgia font. Perhaps the other browsers tries to use another font having an em space or doesn't use the box character to indicate a missing character.

One way to look for the em space character is to use *Character Map* available in *Accessories*. If you check the *Advanced view* check box and selects *Unicode* for the *Character set* and sets *Group by* to *Unicode Subrange* you get a *Group By* box to the right. The em space is found in the *General Punctuation* category. It might be hard to spot as it is... well, a space.

Comment: I'm using Georgia, and I only have 1 type of Georgia on my system. Why would it be fine in Chrome and Firefox, and not in IE6?

Comment: @Skilldrick: It's possible those other browsers will automatically fall back to a different font that does support the requested characters if the current font does not.

Comment: UPDATE: It appears that I was correct. "Major modern web browsers, are capable of font substitution (with the exception of versions of Internet Explorer older than version 7)." (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_substitution )

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Doctype](http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/EmspCharacterEntity) IE6 supports the `&emsp;` character entity, so your font might not.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is that you could find a different font that does do what you want with the em spaces and then just use that; alternatively, you could use a stylesheet and set the text property `word-spacing` to 1em. http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_text_word-spacing.asp

Of course, if you're only using em spaces in some areas and not in others, then you'd be better off just using a similar font that does support em spaces.